# Uniform Convergence and Sup

Tags: uniform-convergence

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be open and let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} : X \to \mathbb{C}$ be a sequence of complex-valued functions. Suppose $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $X$. Fix $a \in X$. **I would like to prove**
$$
\sup_{x \in X} |f_n(x)-f_n(a)| \to \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)-f(a)|.
$$
**I tried** to rewrite
$$
\left| \sup_{x \in X} |f_n(x)-f_n(a)| - \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)-f(a)| \right|
$$
using only one supremum. I thought in general for $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ one has
$$
|\sup A - \sup B| \leq |\sup (A-B)|,
$$
but I don't see how this would help after getting
$$
\sup_{x,y \in X} |f_n(x) - f_n(a)| - |f(y) - f(a)|.
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sketch:
$$ |f_n(x) -f_n(a)| = |f_n(x) -f(x) - f_n(a) + f(a) +f(x) - f(a)|$$
$$ \leq |f_n(x) -f(x)| + |f_n(a) - f(a)| +|f(x) - f(a)|$$

Now take $\sup_{x \in X}$ on both sides, noting that supremum is subadditive. Then take limits to get your result.

Comment: @Amateur: This is only one half. Can you do the rest? If not let me know in comments.

Comment: Well I thought one would then proceed taking the $\sup$ on both sides like you said and note that $\sup |f_n(x)-f(x)|$ and $\sup |f_n(a)-f(a)|$ tend to $0$ by the uniform convergence hypothesis. So letting $n \to \infty$ on both sides we get $\sup |f_n(x)-f_n(a)| \to 0 + 0 + \sup |f(x)-f(a)|$ since $\sup |f(x)-f(a)|$ does not depend on $n$. The only subtlety I see (if there is one) is that we don't really have the form $\sup(A+B+C)$ to apply directly subadditivity and infer $\sup(A+B+C)\leq \sup A+\sup B+\sup C$. Rather we have the $\sup$ of a subset of $A+B+C$ here, so we still have...

Comment: ... the inequality. Is that what you had in mind ? Thanks for your dedication. I always forget to take the $\sup$ *at the end*...

Comment: Actually, I have proven $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup |f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \sup |f(x) - f(a)|$. You still need to prove the reverse inequality...

Comment: Right. Then I apply the same argument, noting that $|f_n(x)-f(x)-f_n(a)+f(a)+f(x)-f(a)| \geq |f(x)-f(a)|-|f_n(x)-f(x)|-|f_n(a)-f(a)|$.

Comment: Yeah. That will do.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f_n$ is a bounded function for any $n$. Denote $g_n(x)=f_n(x)-f_n(a), g(x)=f(x)-f(a)$. Since $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ one gets by the triangle inequality that also $g_n$ converges uniformly to $g$ in particular $||g_n||_{\infty}$ converges to $||g||_{\infty}$.

Comment: Thanks. You think it is important that $f_n$ be a bounded function for every $n$ ?  I think that if the suprema are infinite, the limit still holds ?